# How to create an assembly language?

Tags: assembly, 6502

like the title says How to create an assembly language? I'm new at this programing thing. I've tried to learn Ruby, Python, Java, c, etc. but I'm limited to my phone since I don't have a computer at the moment. I've searched the web over and over again with this question and I haven't found an answer! I know that since I'm extremely new to all of this and that starting with an assembly language I'm in for a long road of frustration, but I'm am old school kinda of guy and I personally believe in starting from the bottom   like the 6502 but I'm so confused at it I don't understand what any of really means actually, so I figured if I could create my own assembly language out of 6502 I might be able to understand it a lot better?!

Anyway my question is: 
How do I create my very own assembly language? 
Can I create it out of 6502?

P.S. the reason I pick the 6502 assembly language is because I'm very interested in the Apple II, Atari, and NES. I absolutely love them! And if you could please don't be so harsh on this newbie?! Lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to understand the [6502 instruction set](http://www.6502.org/tutorials/6502opcodes.html). What each of these codes do & how to use them. Start simple & see if you can work out how to add 2 integers.

An assembly language is for all intents & purposes a list of aliases for  binary codes (machine code), see above link. To create your own you should be comfortable about what each code does then assign it an alias.

Good luck!

Comment: Is there anything that could help for a total beginner?

Comment: I'm afraid that's as simple as it gets. You need to understand the [chips architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6502#Technical_description) & what the codes in the instruction set do.